# Private IP for recaptcha

Tags: recaptcha

Can I use private IP for recaptcha?

I have inserted 192.168.12.16 into Key Settings -> Domains, but when I load the page, it shows me ERROR: Invalid domain for site key.

Comment: that's a local server. it's the same as localhost in wampserver and it would not work. Use public IP only where it represents the domain IP

Comment: localhost is able to work.

Comment: localhost is not working.......